# How to get number of selected node

Tags: sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FlowClientGetNum] 
(@ID_ListGroupParIzm Integer, @ID_ListParIzm Integer) 
 AS   
SELECT
    Number of my @ID_ListParIzm FROM -- sure this string doesn't works --
SELECT  
     C.ID_ListParIzm,
FROM 
     CfgListParIzm C
WHERE 
    C.ID_ListGroupParIzm = @ID_ListGroupParIzm AND 
    C.VisibleOnTab=1 
    ORDER BY C.Num
```

how can I get the number of node from select where ID_ListParIzm=@ID_ListParIzm ?

for example I got from select

```
2
7
8
2
4
68
96
2
3
```

and my value is 8.
Procedure must return 3. (number of 8)

thank you

Comment: You will have to clear this up a little, and tell us what your intensions are, as it is not very clear right now...

Comment: Also, can you show us the entire Select statement? What is *Num* in the *ORDER BY Num*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that you have an ORDER BY you can have a look at using [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Something like

```
SELECT  RowNumber
FROM    (
            SELECT   
                 C.ID_ListParIzm,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C.Num) RowNumber
            FROM  
                 @CfgListParIzm C 
            WHERE  
                C.ID_ListGroupParIzm = @ID_ListGroupParIzm AND  
                C.VisibleOnTab=1
        ) sub
WHERE   ID_ListParIzm = @ID_ListParIzm
```